# How to show that $\Vert$ $\Vert$:X$\rightarrow$R is continuous?

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

Let (X,$\Vert$ $\Vert$) be an NLS. Show that $\Vert$ $\Vert$ : X $\rightarrow$ R is continuous.

For X=$R^n$ i can show that this function is continuous because there $\langle$x,x$\rangle$=$($$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$$)^2$. Then if i consider a sequence ($x_n$) in X that converges to x then by algebra of sequences i can show that $\langle$$x_n$,$x_n$$\rangle$ converges to $\langle$x,x$\rangle$.

But how to show this for arbitary space X. Any hint will be good.

Comment: Use the triangle inequality to show that the norm is Lipschitz with rank one.

Comment: Hint: By the triangle inequality $\left| {\left\| x \right\| - \left\| {x_n } \right\|} \right| \le \left\| {x - x_n } \right\|$.

Answer (score 3):

By reverse triangle inequality we have

$$
\left| \left\|x \right\|- \left\|y\right\|\right|\le \left\|x-y\right\|
$$

Comment: So if i define d(x,y)=$\Vert$x-y$\Vert$ where d be a metric associated with the norm. Now if i consider a sequence ($x_n$) converging to x then for given $\epsilon$ then there exist a p$\in$N such that for all n$\geq$p then d($x_n$,x)<$\epsilon$ then use the reverse triangular inequality to show that ||$x_n$|| converges to ||x||?

Comment: Yes, more simply if the right hand side goes to zero (i.e. $x\to y$ in norm) the left hand side goes to zero (i.e. norm of $x$ goes to norm of $y$).  As stated in the comments, this means the norm is Lipschitz which is more than continuity.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, something similar holds in metric spaces. Let $A$ be a metric space with metric $d$. Let $y\in A$ be fixed. Then the function $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=d(x,y)$, is continuous, where $\mathbb{R}$ has the usual metric.